# how to re-factor a web site for 3G?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, mobile, 3g

I have a traditional web site which serves users from desktop computer browsers. I am using Microsoft technologies, like ASP.Net, C#, .Net, SQL Server 2008, IIS and Windows Server 2008.

Nowadays, more and more users are using 3G mobile phones, and I am wondering from software perspective, how to add new features to my web site (do I need a client application runs on mobile phone as well?) so that 3G users could have good user experience or new kinds of 3G specific applications? Any recommended documents or real samples are welcome.

For 3G users, I want to distinguish from traditional less-powered and slow network access GPRS mobile phone.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd still use ASP.NET for mobiles
http://www.asp.net/mobile/

It's more about the usage of the screen than the download speeds.

Comment: Thanks! It is good resource for mobile. But specific for applications with new features targeted to 3G, any recommendations?

Comment: That depends on what you consider "3G" features? Mobile phones vary so much it's very hard to say "use video" or something like that, it's tough enough designing something taht loads quickly and looks decent on so many devices. Clean neat UI's with good usabilities are universal.

Pushed a bit though, if you're specifically thinking iPhone you could look at something like:
http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioiPhone/

Comment: Best place to start is here:
http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7-series/

These two links are fantastic for WP7:
Designing sites for mobile
http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9713253
WP7 UI guide
http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9713252